Laravel v.11 job don't send email but give no errors
I have this problem with Laravel 11 that I can't solve:
I create a command to retrieve data to send by email and this work correctly:
class SendEvent5Reminder extends Command {
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'send:send-event5-reminder';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle() {
        // Get today's date
        $today = Carbon::today();

        // Calculate the date 5 days from today
        $backDate = $today->copy()->subDays(5);

        // Find all events expiring within 5 days
        $events = Event::whereBetween('start', [$backDate->format('Y-m-d'), $today->format('Y-m-d')])->get();


        // Check if there are any events found
        if ($events->isEmpty()) {
            Log::info('No events expiring within 5 days.');
            return 0;
        }

        // Get the administrator user
        $adminUser = User::get();

        if (!$adminUser) {
            Log::info('No administrator user found.');
            return 1;
        }

        // Dispatch the job to send reminder emails
        foreach ($events as $sendEvent) {
            RemindEmail5Job::dispatch($adminUser, $sendEvent);
        }

        Log::info('Reminder emails sent successfully.');

        return 0;
    }

}

Then I create the Job:
class RemindEmail5Job implements ShouldQueue {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $adminUser;
    protected $sendEvent;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct($adminUser, Event $sendEvent) {
        $this->adminUser = $adminUser;
        $this->sendEvent = $sendEvent;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void {
                Log::info('TEST: Start Job email!');
        $email = new Remind5Event($this->sendEvent);
        Mail::to($this->adminUser->first()->email)->send($email);
>event));
    }
}


But the handle() method don't work and it seems that this method is not even taken into consideration, in fact the log put there for testing is not written.
I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.
Sending test emails via tinker works correctly, but after many tests the job doesn't work.
Why? This all seems correct, but it doesn't go through the handle() method, I just don't understand.

Check your failed_jobs table, also you can add failed method to your job and log the failure message. You can check how to deal with failed jobs for reference

Two possibilities: 1. You exceed your PHP memory_limit (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), because of too much records trying to be loaded, and your php just kills the process. 2. Your job is timed out, also because it could take a long time to process the results that are fetched from the database (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout)

@hassan suggestion was excellent, I tried to look and proceed and understand even better in detail. I cleaned the jobs_failed table and relaunched the jobs but nothing. I use:  echo "" > storage/logs/laravel.log (to clean the log file) and php artisan schedule:test (to relaunch the scheduled job" but into log file only [2024-07-19 09:18:17] production.INFO: Reminder emails sent successfully.  and failed_jobs table remain empty like as if everything was working perfectly, but the email doesn't go out or arrive. it remains a mystery to me.

Regarding the indications of @zlatan
This doesn't seem to be the solution because I also tested with memory_limit = -1, but the problem persists.

After banging my head against the wall and trying a lot of things for days, suddenly the solution appeared and it is simple: do not use job because the handle() method in the job (used in this way) does not work (it's a bug?... I don't know).
Instead call the email class, for sending email, directly from the handle() method of the artisan command, like this (inside the foreach in this case)
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Mail\RemindEvent;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEvent5Reminder extends Command {
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'send:send-event5-reminder';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle() {
        // Get today's date
        $today = Carbon::today();

        // Calculate the date 5 days from today
        $backDate = $today->copy()->subDays(5);

        // Find all events expiring within 5 days
        $events = Event::whereBetween('start', [$backDate->format('Y-m-d'), $today->format('Y-m-d')])->get();


        // Check if there are any events found
        if ($events->isEmpty()) {
            Log::info('No events expiring within 5 days.');
            return 0;
        }

        // Get the administrator user
        $adminUser = User::get();

        if (!$adminUser) {
            Log::info('No administrator user found.');
            return 1;
        }

        // Dispatch the job to send reminder emails
        foreach ($events as $sendEvent) {
            $email = new RemindEvent($sendEvent);
            Mail::to($adminUser->first()->email)->send($email);
        }

        Log::info('Reminder emails sent successfully.');

        return 0;
    }

}

